# SignaturePad does not accept setting the strokes directly

Tags: xamarin.forms, signaturepad

Working with the Xamarin SignaturePage control [(github)](https://github.com/xamarin/SignaturePad).  It captures signature strokes exactly as expected, which we then serialize and store.  When we deserialize the strokes and try to restore them within the control, it just "doesn't take."

We set `SignaturePad.Strokes = strokes` where strokes is a complete array of Xamarin.Forms.Point arrays. But when we check the `Strokes` value after setting it, it is always empty, as if it had not been set.

We've gone as far as trying to build the source code to find the error but were unable to build it. Does anyone have any other ideas of what could be wrong?

Thank you for your help!